# Performance problems reading lots of small files using libssh2

Tags: libssh2

I am trying to read lots of small files using libssh2.
I am currently using libssh2_scp_recv/libssh2_channel_read and I have also tried libssh2_sftp_open/libssh2_sftp_read.

With large files, I am able to get a speed similar to scp. But with small files most of my time is passed opening a handle to my remote file (libssh2_scp_recv) and not downloading the file (libssh2_channel_read).

How does scp does it? 
Is there a simple way to batch download multiple files so I will be able to saturate my connection?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you write your own SFTP layer on top of libssh able to use pipelining.

Maybe an easier solution would be to use several threads, every one establishing an independent SSH connection in order to retrieve several files in parallel.